# Alternative to groupBy in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, grouping, shuffle, window-functions

I have a Dataframe df with next info:

```
id   json_data
1    {a: "1", b: "2"} 
1    {a: "1", b: "3"} 
1    {a: "1", b: "4"}
2    {a: "1", b: "2"} 
2    {a: "1", b: "6"}
```

And I need the next final result:

```
id   json_data
1    [{a: "1", b: "2"},{a: "1", b: "3"},{a: "1", b: "4"}]
2    [{a: "1", b: "2"},{a: "1", b: "6"}]
```

I tried two different approaches, using Window functions and groupBy respectively. With both approaches I am getting the desired result.

1º approach:

```
var user_window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("id")
val df2 = df.withColumn("json_data",
    collect_list($"json_data").over(user_window))
          .withColumn("rank", row_number().over(user_window))
          .where("rank = 1")
```

2º approach:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy(df("id")).agg(collect_list($"json_data").as("json_data"))
```

With both approaches I am getting same performance. But reading documentation about Spark, it seems both approaches are not efficient, since rows with the same key will need to travel across the cluster (shuffled) to be together. I am showing a small example, because in production I have a high volume of data. And doing the group or using Window functions it takes a long time.

Any alternatives in order to do it?

Comment: What you are asking is basically how to perform a "group by" more efficiently than by performing a group by. I'm not sure that we can help you, unless you tell us more about your data (is it unbalanced? etc.). However, if you are performing a "group by" as an intermediate operation to achieve something else, we may be able to help you achieve that end purpose more efficiently if you tell us what it is.

Comment: I you can change the source tables, then you could use `bucketing`... If the table is bucketed by `id`, then no shuffling will occur if you do  a `groupBy($"id"`)

Comment: I wouldsuggest you to use custom partitioning when you created the dataframe so that data with same id goes to same executor. then groupby should be good

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I am wondering if you mean do something like this: df.write.bucketBy(10, "id").saveAsTable("df_table").

Comment: @sylvinho81 yes. I you red from such a table, there should be no "Exchange"  (shuffling) in the physical plan when you do a groupBy

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I did a try, and it takes more time doing the bucketing and then groupBy than doing only the groupBy.

Answer (score -1):

My advice would be using reduceByKey.

This way, if your key is `id` and your value (at the beggining) is `json_data` in a list, then performing reduceByKey, along with the concatenation function, of the various `json_data` wrapped lists would give you a better performance.

In a nutshell, using reduceByKey first does the "groupBy" within the partition, and only afterwards starts the shuffling of the data.

A good place to read on the performance difference of groupByKey and reduceByKey is [here](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/cs100x-2015-introduction-to-big-data/module-2--spark-tutorial-lab.html) (part `6b`).

In pyspark it will look like this:

```
rdd = df.rdd
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: (row['id'], [row['json_data']]))
rdd = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Comment: I don't think that `reduceByKey` will be much faster, because no real aggregaton is done, i.e. the size of the aggregation buffer is the same as the size of the records themself.

Comment: Have you read the provided link?
The diagram demonstrates how reduceByKey can be better than groupBy.
Using groupBy requires a lot of shuffling in this case comparing to reduceByKey.

Comment: I know the difference between  groupBy and reduceByKey... I also made some benchmarks comparing those with this kind of data : RDD's reduceByKey was slower by a factor of two compared to DataFrames groupBy

Comment: The link is about the difference between `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey`. There is actually a large difference between `groupByKey` and the dataframe operation `groupBy` and in nearly all situations, `groupBy` should be preferred.